# Elasticsearch is not starting after re-installation

Tags: elasticsearch, service

I recently noted that Elasticsearch was not starting after a reboot. Eventualy I deleted it and re-installed from scratch. However I'm still having the same problem. When I try to start it, systemctl shows the following status:

```
$ sudo systemctl status elasticsearch
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Wed 2020-09-16 16:22:32 EDT; 3min 23s ago
       Docs: https://www.elastic.co
    Process: 1716 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/systemd-entrypoint -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet (code=exited, status=143)
   Main PID: 1716 (code=exited, status=143)

Sep 16 16:20:59 enk-network-sniffer systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
Sep 16 16:22:29 enk-network-sniffer systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Sep 16 16:22:32 enk-network-sniffer systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Sep 16 16:22:32 enk-network-sniffer systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
```

Looking at

> /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log

shows the following logs:

```
   [2020-09-16T16:42:33,268][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [enk-network-sniffer] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/sda5)]], net usable_space [23.4gb], net total_space [38.6gb], types [ext4]
[2020-09-16T16:42:33,301][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [enk-network-sniffer] heap size [1gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2020-09-16T16:42:33,717][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [enk-network-sniffer] node name [enk-network-sniffer], node ID [RljBYx0ZQx6E87E__MV3gQ], cluster name [elasticsearch]
[2020-09-16T16:42:33,720][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [enk-network-sniffer] version[7.7.1], pid[1690], build[default/deb/ad56dce891c901a492bb1ee393f12dfff473a423/2020-05-28T16:30:01.040088Z], OS[Linux/5.4.0-47-generic/amd64], JVM[AdoptOpenJDK/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/14.0.1/14.0.1+7]
[2020-09-16T16:42:33,721][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [enk-network-sniffer] JVM home [/usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk]
[2020-09-16T16:42:33,722][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [enk-network-sniffer] JVM arguments [-Xshare:auto, -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.locale.providers=SPI,COMPAT, -Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseG1GC, -XX:G1ReservePercent=25, -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch-8868144046098870714, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/lib/elasticsearch, -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/elasticsearch/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=536870912, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=deb, -Des.bundled_jdk=true]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,521][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,522][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [analysis-common]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,531][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [constant-keyword]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,531][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [flattened]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,532][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [frozen-indices]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,535][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,535][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [ingest-geoip]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,536][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [ingest-user-agent]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,538][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,539][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,543][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,543][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [mapper-extras]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,547][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [parent-join]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,548][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [percolator]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,551][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [rank-eval]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,552][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [reindex]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,552][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [repository-url]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,555][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [search-business-rules]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,556][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [spatial]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,556][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [systemd]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,561][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [tasks]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,562][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [transform]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,562][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,565][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [vectors]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,567][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-analytics]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,571][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-async-search]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,574][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-autoscaling]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,574][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-ccr]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,577][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-core]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,580][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-deprecation]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,581][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-enrich]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,582][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-eql]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,583][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-graph]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,586][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-identity-provider]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,588][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-ilm]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,592][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-logstash]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,593][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-ml]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,594][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-monitoring]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,602][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-ql]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,602][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-rollup]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,602][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-security]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,612][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-sql]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,612][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-voting-only-node]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,633][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-watcher]
[2020-09-16T16:42:54,634][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] no plugins loaded
```

I'm not being able to find any error or warning in these files. Any idea on what might be wrong or where else I can look at to find more clues?

UPDATE:

Here is the /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml file:

```
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
#node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
#
# Path to log files:
#
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
network.host: 0.0.0.0
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
#cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
#
discovery.type: single-node
cluster.initial_master_nodes: []
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
#gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the gateway module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
```

After increasing the heap size, I obtained the following logs:

```
[2020-09-17T11:47:21,107][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [enk-network-sniffer] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/sda5)]], net usable_space [174.4gb], net total_space [196.1gb], types [ext4]
[2020-09-17T11:47:21,129][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [enk-network-sniffer] heap size [4gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2020-09-17T11:47:23,118][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [enk-network-sniffer] node name [enk-network-sniffer], node ID [RljBYx0ZQx6E87E__MV3gQ], cluster name [elasticsearch]
[2020-09-17T11:47:23,128][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [enk-network-sniffer] version[7.7.1], pid[1966], build[default/deb/ad56dce891c901a492bb1ee393f12dfff473a423/2020-05-28T16:30:01.040088Z], OS[Linux/5.4.0-47-generic/amd64], JVM[AdoptOpenJDK/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/14.0.1/14.0.1+7]
[2020-09-17T11:47:23,129][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [enk-network-sniffer] JVM home [/usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk]
[2020-09-17T11:47:23,129][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [enk-network-sniffer] JVM arguments [-Xshare:auto, -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.locale.providers=SPI,COMPAT, -Xms4g, -Xmx4g, -XX:+UseG1GC, -XX:G1ReservePercent=25, -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch-11788675126322072724, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/lib/elasticsearch, -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/elasticsearch/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2147483648, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=deb, -Des.bundled_jdk=true]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,845][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,845][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [analysis-common]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,849][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [constant-keyword]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,850][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [flattened]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,850][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [frozen-indices]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,850][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,850][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [ingest-geoip]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,851][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [ingest-user-agent]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,852][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,852][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,853][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,853][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [mapper-extras]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,854][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [parent-join]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,854][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [percolator]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,855][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [rank-eval]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,855][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [reindex]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,856][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [repository-url]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,856][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [search-business-rules]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,856][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [spatial]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,856][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [systemd]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,857][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [tasks]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,857][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [transform]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,858][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,858][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [vectors]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,859][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-analytics]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,860][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-async-search]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,860][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-autoscaling]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,860][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-ccr]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,861][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-core]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,861][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-deprecation]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,862][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-enrich]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,862][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-eql]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,862][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-graph]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,863][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-identity-provider]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,863][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-ilm]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,864][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-logstash]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,864][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-ml]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,865][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-monitoring]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,867][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-ql]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,868][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-rollup]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,868][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-security]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,868][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-sql]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,869][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-voting-only-node]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,869][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] loaded module [x-pack-watcher]
[2020-09-17T11:47:54,870][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [enk-network-sniffer] no plugins loaded
```

ES is still failing to start.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you look in `/var/log/messages` to see if there is anything there ?

Comment: Yes, logs are included. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no error message, its difficult to pinpoint to the exact cause, but could you provide your `elasticsearch.yml` and I also see you have defined `1gb` of Heap space, could you try increasing it?

Only interesting this in the logs are:

> Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Wed 2020-09-16 16:22:32 EDT;
> 3min 23s ago
> Docs: https://www.elastic.co
> Process: 1716 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/systemd-entrypoint -p
> ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet (code=exited, status=143)    Main
> PID: 1716 (code=exited, status=143)

You can notice the `timeout` and `143 status` and you can read more about it in

https://serverfault.com/questions/695849/services-remain-in-failed-state-after-stopped-with-systemctl and see if you can figure out the error logs or more info to debug the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I increased the heap size to 4G but still no joy. I have added the elasticsearch.yml file for reference.